# How can i open the same project in several windows?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I have a big project with several subproject and i would need a window for each sub project.

I do :

`bash> sublime_text --project $path_to_project &`

bash> sublime_text --project $path_to_project &

First command open a window. so far so good.
Second command brings me back to the windows opened.

How force sublime text to open the same project in several windows ?

Answer (score 5):

Sublime text's command line options includes a new window option `-n`.

Here's an example using your code above:

```
bash> sublime_text --project $path_to_project -n
```

This will open the project with a brand new window, instead of focusing your already opened project.
For reference here's [the documentation on sublimes command line arguments](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Comment: That works, thanks! However ending '&' symbol is not necessary, also instead of typing out 'sublime_text' there's a shorthand 'subl'

Answer (score 4):

First save the project by clicking on `Project -> Save Project As..`

Then save the project. Sublime will create two files `[name].sublime-project` and `[name].sublime-workspace`.

Then follow Mike McFarland's response  Open command line and run the following command

```
$ subl --project /path/to/[name].sublime-project -n
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about opening a new window entirely but keep the project workspace in both windows (ie all the folders in your sidebar):
 1. Open and configure your project in one window/instance of Sublime Text 3
 2. Go to the top menu and hit `Project -> New Workspace For Project`

I also like to replace the default new window shorcut to run this command. You can update your user keymap with: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+n"], "command": "new_window_for_project" }`

Comment: `Project -> New Workspace For Project` is the most convenient way for me :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu on top and hit:

```
File > New View into File
```

It will open your same file in a new `tab`. You can do this multiple times.

Another option is:

```
File > New Window
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

This will open new Sublime Text `window`. Then drag your file into it. You can again do this multiple times.

Comment: Does not work. Think there was a misunderstanding, so i edited the question

Answer (score -1):

Even though the OP gives opening from CLI as an example, the headline seems to be worded more general. So here is a GUI only solution: Open a new Window, then in the "Project" Menu, just click "Open Project" instead of "Quick Switch Project" or "Open Recent". This way, you can re-open the same project in different windows as often as you want.

Comment: This open does not give me the project view in the sidebar. I'd like to have the folder configuration I created for a project available on two separate monitors.